# burp site displays the ajax call url of WebAPI and its paramters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have created a ASP.Net MVC 5 application which includes WebAPI. Web API will be called via JS file by  passing url, parameters and result will be JSON.

While doing security testing in burp site tool the WebAPI URL, methods and parameters are displayed.

Kindly help me to not display the URL, methods & parameters in security testing.

Thanks in advance.

This is happen in the security testing tool burpsuite.

WebAPI Controller method:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]
public JToken GetValues(string Code)
{
            return JToken.FromObject(TestManager.Instance.GetValues(Code));
        }
```

WebAPI call using JS File:

```
Service = {
    // All Ajax function call
    getData: function (url, dataType, parameters, async, type) {
        var GridData = '';

        $.ajax({
            //url: url, dataType: dataType, type: type, data: JSON.stringify(parameters), async: async, success: function (data) {
            //    GridData = data;
            //},
            url: url, dataType: dataType, type: type, data: parameters, async: async, success: function (data) {
                GridData = data;
            },
            //error: function (error) {
            //    alert('Error occured');
            //}
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.responseJSON.ExceptionMessage);
            }
        });
        return GridData;
    }
}
```

Controller JS file calls the WebAPI JS page:

```
var IsExists = Service.getData(window.rootUrl + 'api/MasterApi/GetValues', 'json', { Code: Code }, false, 'GET');
```

Comment: maybe I'm not understanding but there isn't a way you can just hide the request/response from a man in the middle (burp in this case acts as your man in the middle as it's a reverse proxy inspecting network traffic) the same holds true with tools like fiddler, etc. This isn't a security concern either. Any data you want to be unknown should be posted in a request body and encrypted over TLS 1.2+ (and possible encrypted) and authentication/authorization to use your api should be handled appropriately. Just knowing the api endpoint and accepted http verbs is not a vulnerability

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to understand your comments. In the burp site it directly exposes the API method name and its parameters. In burp site, it displays URL as 'appName/api/MasterApi/GetValues?Code=1'. I want to hide the API method name and its parameters during security testing. If it is exposed, hackers can change the value & methods as well. Please note this API method will be called from dropdown change event via JS page. Kindly suggest how to handle it.

Comment: Again, there's no way to hide requests from showing up in burp. Burp/Fiddler/etc will see every single request that goes through it. Hackers can certainly change values and methods. The way to prevent this from being a vulnerability is to post sensitive data in the request body over https, verify the user's identity (authentication), verify the user has access to the data they're requesting, (authorization), generally all data being changed/updated should live in the request body as a post/put so its encrypted via https and the values cant just be changed. viewmodel constraints help as well

Comment: Yes, even though I have enabled 'HTTPS' it display the parameter value and methods. We cannot able to verify the authorization on dropdown list change in ajax call. Please let me know, do you any code snippet to check the ajax call as validate call. Thanks in advance and anticipating your response.

Comment: You need to validate everything server side. Validation/authorization/authenticatiom are all going to depend on the app- i.e: your auth scheme, what data needs to be protected, etc.